# Parallel Execution of SSIS (ETL) across multiple SQL databases

Tags: sql, performance, ssis

I have multitenancy database (one DB per customer). And at present we have set the SQL memory to 60 percent of RAM and running ETL across one site at a time.

Is it possible to run ETLs across multiple sites/database at the same time?

Note - During ETL execution other operation would be slow as ETL uses maximum RAM, hence wanted to know can two ETLs be run at a same across different database.

Comment: What does ETL do? Export data to the centralized database? Do all of your databases run on the same server, so sharing the resources? Is the DWH in the same server as the customers databases, or in another server / cloud?

Comment: ETL imports data to the different site base. Each ETL to one DB. 
All db runs on the same server. Even Master DB is deployed in the same Server

Comment: What is the import strategy? Is it Upsert or Truncate + Reload? Are you using staging tables?

Comment: Truncate + Reload on the staging tables

Answer (score 0):

SSIS Packages can be executed in parallel. However, as your Operational databases are on the same server, and the database that you are importing to is also on the same server, I am failing to see how that would speed up the ETL, unless the databases are on separate disks which can help parallelize the reads and writes.

Also it may be more dangerous, as if you cannot afford running ETL at the point in time (like when the businesses open), you will have to stop all packages, and then restart all of them